Power Apps Form integrated with SharePoint List refuses to connect
We’ve been experiencing persistent connectivity issues with the Power Apps form that is integrated with our SharePoint List when used on Microsoft Edge. When opening the Power App Form, many of our employees are seeing the “apps.gov.powerapps.us refused to connect” error. Here’s a bit more context on the issue:
Temporary Fix: We’ve advised our team to clear the cache and cookies on Microsoft Edge as a temporary workaround. This seems to resolve the issue initially, but the error reappears when they re-open the Power Apps form, requiring them to clear the cache again.
Has anybody else experienced something like this or know of any permanent solutions? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.
